# WindowsTokenRoleProvider Catastrophic Failure

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, asp.net-2.0

I'm having a *really* frustrating error trying to secure an ASP.NET application using the WindowsTokenRoleProvider.  For a particular user I'm seeing the following ProviderException thrown:

```
API failed due to error 'Catastrophic failure
```

As I said, this only seems to happen for a particuar user, I seem to be able to access the site fine and so have several colleagues.  The only difference between us and the failing user is that they are *not* an administrator on the box where the site is being hosted.

From the call to GetRolesForUser.  From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.windowstokenroleprovider.getrolesforuser.aspx) it states that this can happen because of the following:

1. The currently executing user does
   not have an authenticated
   WindowsIdentity attached to
   Page.User. For non-HTTP
   scenarios, the currently executing
   user does not have an authenticated
   WindowsIdentity attached to
   Thread.CurrentPrincipal.
2. username does not match the Name of
   the current WindowsIdentity.
3. A failure occurred while retrieving
   the user's Windows group
   information.

I'm suspecting the issue *may* be related to point 3 as I've managed to use the .NET Framework debugging ability in Visual Studio 2008 to debug the code and it seems to be failing calling:

```
UnsafeNativeMethods.GetGroupsForUser
```

What I can't understand is why!  And if the call is failing in a Framework library then I'm not entirely sure what I can do to resolve the issue.

Any help or suggestions on this would be grately received as I'm at a loss as to where I go from here, I'm seriously considering scrapping using the role provider in place of some other less elegant method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after some very helpful input from a Microsoft ADC I've managed to resolve the issue.

The call to UnsafeNativeMethods.GetGroupsForUser should return a list of *all* AD groups which a particular user has access to (this is recursive, so will also include parent groups etc).  It appears that *sometimes* when migrating AD profiles between domains a user can end up with an erroneous SID pointing to a group with no name associated with it.  Because the call tries to grab all the SID names for a particular profile it will fail when it gets to the null entry resulting in the (rather unhelpful) "catastrophic failure" error above.

Just as a reference, the group was showing up in a dump from the whoami command line tool as follows (other groups, SIDs and domain name masked):

```
DOMAIN\   Deleted account   S-1-2-34-123456789-123456789-123456789-12345   Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
```

As you can see, the domain name is present, but the group is not.  The resolution was to get a domain administrator to remove the entry from the user's profile.

I truly hope this one helps others to resolve this issue because it had me *completely* flummoxed!